# How do I get the values from an arbitrary number of checkboxes? (tkinter, python)

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, tkinter

I'm currently trying to create n number of checkboxes from n number of sheets in an excel workbook to choose whether or not to use corresponding sheets.

I am having difficulty with accessing the state of each checkbox since it seems like I need a variable predefined for each checkbox's 'variable' to draw the state of the checkbox from. Upon looking for how to create a list of new variables through for loops I have found that this is very bad practice and should not be done because analogous results can be found from using dictionaries.

```
import openpyxl;
import pandas;
import string;
from openpyxl import Workbook;
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from tkinter import font as tkFont


root=Tk()
root.configure(background='black')
style=ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')
masterlst=[]
def selector():
    for i in vardict:
        print(i.get())
    

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Python Test.xlsx');
def choose_sheets(workbook):
    global w
    w=Frame(root,background='black')
    global lst2
    lst2=[]*len(workbook.sheetnames)
    w.pack()
    lst=[]
    global vardict
    vardict={}
    dictvar={}
    for i in range(len(workbook.sheetnames)):
        dictvar['var '+str(i)]=0
    for i in range(len(workbook.sheetnames)):
        vardict['var '+str(i)]=IntVar
    for i,j,k in zip(workbook.sheetnames,vardict,range(len(workbook.sheetnames))):
        j=j
        dictvar['var '+str(k)] = Checkbutton(w, text=str(i),background='black',foreground='white',activebackground='black',activeforeground='white',selectcolor='gray',command=selector,offvalue=0,onvalue=1,variable=vardict[j])
    for i,j in zip(dictvar,range(len(workbook.sheetnames))):
        dictvar[i].pack()
    
print(masterlst)
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to do this properly as when running the below code I get the error:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`
which makes sense considering how I would require a variable to obtain this. I tried lists as well but cannot find a way to access the state of each widget without setting a predefined variable for the state of each widget, something I cannot do for n number of sheets in an excel file unless I decide to create a set number of variables beforehand. Please let me know if there are any workarounds to obtaining the state of each checkbox widget.

Comment: Your `vardict` contains N copes of the `IntVar` constructor. because you never called the function.  You need `vardict['var '+str(i)] = IntVar()`,

Comment: Apart from Tim comment, `for i in vardict` will go through the *keys* of `vardict`, not those `IntVar()`.  Use `for i in vardict.values()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Tim Roberts and @acw1668, both of your solutions have solved my issue and I am now able to get the checkbox states for n number of checkboxes! For anyone that would like to see what the corrected code looks like:

```
import openpyxl;
import pandas;
import string;
from openpyxl import Workbook;
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from tkinter import font as tkFont


root=Tk()
root.configure(background='black')
style=ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')
masterlst=[]
def selector():
    for i in vardict.values():
        print(i.get())
    

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Python Test.xlsx');
def choose_sheets(workbook):
    global w
    w=Frame(root,background='black')
    global lst2
    lst2=[]*len(workbook.sheetnames)
    w.pack()
    lst=[]
    global vardict
    vardict={}
    dictvar={}
    for i in range(len(workbook.sheetnames)):
        dictvar['var '+str(i)]=0
    for i in range(len(workbook.sheetnames)):
        vardict['var '+str(i)]=IntVar()
    for i,j,k in zip(workbook.sheetnames,vardict,range(len(workbook.sheetnames))):
        j=j
        dictvar['var '+str(k)] = Checkbutton(w, text=str(i),background='black',foreground='white',activebackground='black',activeforeground='white',selectcolor='gray',command=selector,offvalue=0,onvalue=1,variable=vardict[j])
    for i,j in zip(dictvar,range(len(workbook.sheetnames))):
        dictvar[i].pack()
    
print(masterlst)

        
        
        

    

choose_sheets(wb)



root.mainloop()
```